# What does git add *.c command do?

Tags: git

I understand that `$ git add .` adds all modified and new (untracked) files in the current directory and all subdirectories to the staging area, but I am confused on the use of the `c` in this command.

Is `.c` just a C source file extension?

Comment: If you run `echo *.c` you will see what *.c expands to in your directory.

Comment: As @nos implied, it's actually the *shell* (command line interpreter) that expands the `*` here. This is called "globbing". The result is that the shell runs `git add a.c b.c c.c` or whatever matches `*.c`. It works for all commands, not just Git. Git has its own built-in globbing as well, so that if you protect the asterisk from the shell, `git add '*.c'`, it still works—but `echo` does not, so `echo '*.c'` just prints `*.c`". (For way too much more on this topic, see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/3795/pattern-matching-and-regular-expressions#t=20170305131800301894)

Comment: It's glob, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep you understood it correctly.
It will add all the `*.c` files to your index.

This is the result of executing git add `*.c`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`git add .` stages all modified or untracked files in current directory and all subdirectories.

`git add *.c` adds all files with `.c` extension. `*` is called "a star wildcard" and it matches any characters. Eg. if you wanted to add any files with extension starting with `.c`, you could achieve it with `git add *.c*`.

Comment: IMO it is worth mentioning that it is the shell that is expanding `*.c` and therefore this is only `.c` files _in the current directory_, not any `.c` file that may be available for adding in the entire repo. (In contrast to `git add .` which will traverse directories finding things.)